# Can I find a similar software as Pageant in Linux?

Tags: svn, ubuntu

Now I am using SVN+SSH in Ubuntu linux, and one problem I have now is that every time I update or commit codes I have to type the "passphrase". In Windows, thanks to Pageant I can only type once, and therefore I am wondering whether there are similar software in Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Seahorse for linux

http://www.debianadmin.com/ssh-key-authentication-using-seahorse-gui.html

Keychain works well too

http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/keychain

Comment: could you tell me how to use seahorse to store the passphase of SVN? Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/186575/whats-the-best-way-to-store-an-encrypted-svn-password-on-ubuntu-server